# CLCompile /MP parallel group?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

When using /MP, compilation of all .cpp in a project will be done in parallel IF the files are using the same compilation options.
For example:

- stdafx.cpp // create PCH
- a.cpp // use PCH
- b.cpp // use PCH
- c.cpp // use PCH
- d.cpp // not using PCH

will be build like this:

- stdafx;
- then (a+b+c) (in parallel);
- then d

Is it possible to launch distinct group in parallel as well ?
I would like it this way:

- (stdafx+d) in parallel;
- then (a+b+c) in parallel

Is it possible ?

The question is not specific to Precompiled header.
The same apply if I want to compile {a.cpp (default), b.cpp (warning as error)}. a.cpp will be done first, then b.cpp

Comment: Just RTFM, the /Yc option is explicitly listed as not being compatible with /MP.

Comment: It's not only Yc, it's all kind of options. Be it "generate precompiled header", "use precompiled header", "warning as error", "clr"...
Each group of "option set" will be compiled in sequence.. And there is no reason to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I can think of would be to place those distinct groupings into separate projects, and utilized the ability to build projects in parallel as well.  However, that complicates setting up and using the precompiled header.

Comment: It is a possible workaround yes, but is it the only one ?
I'm working on a legacy project, and this kind of refactoring is not trivial (sadly).

Comment: It is the only one I can think of, not necessarily the only one.